# Update the Mongo DB COllection with Yesterday Date in a Particular Format

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to Update the Mongo DB COllection with Yesterday Date in this format (YYYY-MM-DD)

I am trying this way

```
var currentDate = new Date();
            currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()-1);
            var month = (currentDate.getMonth() < 9 ? "0"+ (currentDate.getMonth()+1) : (currentDate.getMonth()+1));
            var day = (currentDate.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getDate() : currentDate.getDate());
            var date = currentDate.getTime();
            var patt = date;


    db.LoginCount.update({yesterday : {$exists : false}}, {$set: {yesterday : new Date(date)}})
```

The Output  i am geting is

```
 db.LoginCount.find().pretty()
{
        "yesterday" : ISODate("2013-05-01T03:25:28.640Z")
}
```

PLease tell me how to update COllection so that it  inserts Date in this format YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway i solved this way

```
m = function() { emit(this.cust_id, 1); }

r = function (k, vals) { var sum = 0; for (var i in vals) { sum += vals[i]; } return sum; }

q = function() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()-1);
    var month = (currentDate.getMonth() < 9 ? "0"+ (currentDate.getMonth()+1) : (currentDate.getMonth()+1));
    var day = (currentDate.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getDate() : currentDate.getDate());
    var date = currentDate.getTime();
    var patt = date;
    var query = {"created_at":"2013-04-30 11:19:52.587"};
    return query;
}

res = db.logins.mapReduce(m, r, { query : q(), out :  "LoginCount" });
var yesterday = new Date(Date.now() - 86400000);
db.LoginCount.update({yesterday : {$exists : false}}, {$set: {yesterday : yesterdayday}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $set is using a Date typed value for the yesterday field value. That's why your find query returns an ISODate. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/.

If you really need yesterday to be a string, you will need use:

```
{$set: {yesterday:currentDate.toISOString().substring(0,10)}}
```

If you want to store the date as a Date typed field with a normalized time component (e.g. 00:00:00) use something like this:

```
var d = new Date(Date)
{$set {yesterday:new Date(Date.UTC(currentDate.getUTCFullYear(), currentDate.getUTCMonth(), currentDate.getUTCDate(), 0,0,0))}}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error> db.LoginCount.update({yesterday : {$exists : false}}, {{$set: {yesterday:currentDate.toISOString().substring(0,10)}}})
Thu May 02 12:00:18 SyntaxError: invalid property id (shell):1

Comment: From the mongo shell: > version()
2.4.3
> var currentDate = new Date()
> db.docs.insert({yesterday:currentDate.toISOString().substring(0,10)})
> db.docs.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51827c0fdacd39ce16320384"), "yesterday" : "2013-05-02" }